# How to get all the result columns from database with other custom(concat, sum, count) columns in Jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a table Table1 with 6 columns.

Here is the sql statement that i need to map.

```
Select *,count(ID) as IdCount from Table1;
```

Now, the sql query result will be 7 columns ( 6 Table1 columns and 1 IdCount column). But when i implement the same in Jooq with this query, it only gets a single column "IDCount".

```
SelectQuery q = factory.selectQuery();
        q.addSelect(Table1.ID.count().as("IdCount"));
        q.addFrom(Table1.TABLE1);
```

Now, the resultant recordset have only a single column "IdCount" while what i need is all the columns and one additional column "IdCount". I want 7 columns in Jooq too.

Comment: What are you trying to do in SQL? Before you can map your SQL statements to jOOQ, you have to have a clear idea of your SQL statement itself...

Comment: Modified the question! Hoping that you will answer it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Option 1** (using the asterisk):

The `*` (asterisk, star) operator has been added to jOOQ 3.11 through [`DSL.asterisk()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#asterisk--) (unqualified asterisk) or through [`Table.asterisk()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Table.html#asterisk--) (qualified asterisk). It can be used like any other column being projected.

Prior to jOOQ 3.11, there were the following other options as well:

**Option 2** (with the DSL syntax):

```java
List<Field<?>> fields = new ArrayList<Field<?>>();
fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(Table1.TABLE1.fields()));
fields.add(Table1.ID.count().as("IdCount"));

Select<?> select = ctx.select(fields).from(Table1.TABLE1);
```

**Option 3** (with the "regular" syntax, which you used):

```java
SelectQuery q = factory.selectQuery();
q.addSelect(Table1.TABLE1.fields());
q.addSelect(Table1.ID.count().as("IdCount"));
q.addFrom(Table1.TABLE1);
```

**Option 4** (added in a later version of jOOQ):

```java
// For convenience, you can now specify several "SELECT" clauses
ctx.select(Table1.TABLE1.fields())
   .select(Table1.ID.count().as("IdCount")
   .from(Table1.TABLE1);
```

All of the above options are using the [`Table.fields()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TableLike.html#fields%28%29) method, which of course relies on such meta information being present at runtime, e.g. by using the code generator.

Comment: Great answer, very helpful thanks, but just FYI, in the version of jOOQ I'm using (jOOQ 3.6) the fields method returns a `Field[]`, so in option 1 you have to write `fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(Table1.TABLE1.fields()))`

Comment: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/select-clause/#N4CC5A - asterisk is supported by jooq. I could not make it work but it should :)

Comment: @MaksimGumerov: I'm assuming your referring to this problem here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7841. I will reply to that issue shortly. Thanks for documenting it!