# How to select from only one table in jOOQ using a query with a join?

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I have the following query in jOOQ:

```java
factory()
.select()
.from(PERSON)
.join(ENDUSER).on(ENDUSER.PERSON_FK.equal(PERSON.ID))
.where(ENDUSER.ID.equal(userId))
.fetchOne();
```

This query returns to me a Record with all columns from PERSON and ENDUSER, but I only want the columns from PERSON (that's why I put `.from(PERSON)` and not `.from(PERSON, ENDUSER)`).
I know it doesn't matter that much but I don't want unnecessary fields to be returned.

Comment: I'm a bit undecided whether this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5832803/521799, actually

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can access the fields in `PERSON` through the `Table.fields()` method:

```java
factory()
.select(PERSON.fields()) // Or getFields() in jOOQ 2.x
.from(PERSON)
.join(ENDUSER)...
```

This is about the same as writing

```sql
SELECT PERSON.*
FROM PERSON
JOIN ENDUSER ...
```

Another option is to actually list all the fields from person one by one

Answer (score 10):

Lukas's answer was exactly what I was looking for.  You can also use the `into()` method to get a strongly typed response object back for only the table you care about (instead of the generic `Record` type):

```
PersonRecord record = factory()
  .select()
  .from(PERSON)
  .join(ENDUSER).on(ENDUSER.PERSON_FK.equal(PERSON.ID))
  .where(ENDUSER.ID.equal(userId))
  .fetchOne()
  .into(PERSON);
```

Comment: Save me a hour. Thank you a lot