# How to add a new column in JOOQ?

Tags: jooq

I want to translate this SQL query, in JOOQ.
I want the new field from calculated value, but here i just add it with constant value.

```
select
  *,
  100 as "newField"
from author
```

I tried this

```java
Result<Record> r=create.select(DSL.asterisk(),DSL.val(100).as("newField"))
                    .from(DSL.table("author"))
                    .fetch();
```

That generates this SQL (which looks fine)

```sql
select
  *,
  ? as "newField"
from author
```

But i get this as result (expected is all table with 1 extra column with value 100)

```
+--------+
|newField|
+--------+
|1       |
|2       |
+--------+
```

In pgAdmin, the sql above query does what i need(adds a new field to the table with all values 100).
I don't know what i do wrong, the results seems like `newField` gets as value the row number.

Also in SQL generation how i can print the SQL with the `100` value instead of `?`

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5832803/521799

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation, the usage of `asterisk()` with a plain SQL query is limited: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7841

Workarounds include:

- Using the code generator ([which is always a good idea](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/))
- Wrapping the query in another [derived table](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/derived-tables/), and selecting the `asterisk()` alone in the outer most query

> Also in SQL generation how i can print the SQL with the 100 value instead of ?

That's a different question, not strictly related. There are various ways to generate inline values in jOOQ. In your case, probably `Query.getSQL(paramType.INLINED)` could help you "print" the SQL. Though, you might have had something else in mind, in case of which I recommend asking a new question with more details about this.